# failed to get state value in render of jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
render() {
    const { params } = this.props;
    const actionId = params.id;

    console.log(actionId) // has value

    return(
        <div>
           {this.actionId}
        </div>
    )
 }
```

I don't see any output with above code, I wonder why. I can see the value in the console. What's wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You are already storing the `params.id` in `actionId` variable, so use it directly, remove `this` keyword, like this:

```
render() {
    const { params } = this.props;
    const actionId = params.id;

    console.log(actionId) // has value

    return(
        <div>
           {actionId}
        </div>
    )
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

`this.actionId` is not defined in your context , `this` is refer to the component in self

```
render() {
    const { params } = this.props;
    const actionId = params.id;

    console.log(actionId) // has value

    return(
        <div>
           {actionId}
        </div>
    )
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes I agree with the above answer.
But why don't you just do that ? :

```
render() {

 console.log(this.props.id) // has value

 return(
     <div>
        {this.props.id}
     </div>
  )
}
```

I think that using `params` as an alias on `this.props` will be confusing for other developers, if you share your project in the future. And you complicate your code for nothing.

Comment: reason is lets say he is passing 5 values in props, then each time he has to write `this.props.`, but using `{params} = this.props`, he can easily avoid that, and it make code more readable, and small.